# Play dependencies on a scala project

Tags: scala, dependencies, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to get a play project to have another local scala project as a dependency. I have the local scala project deploying to my local M2 repository with this line in my configuration file.

```
publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file",  new File(Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository")))
```

And I am trying to load the dependency in my play project with this line

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "com.experimentalcork" %% "timeywimeyentities" % "0.0.2"
)

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(   
    resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://" + Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/.m2/repository",testOptions in Test := Nil 
)
```

In the logs as I do a 'play compile' it states that it can not find the dependency. It is looking in the place where I specified the dependency would be.

```
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
[warn]   file://C:/Users/caelrin/.m2/repository/com/experimentalcork/timeywimeyentities_2.9.1/0.0.2/timeywimeyentities_2.9.1-0.0.2.pom
```

And when I go to check that directory, I can confirm that the pom and jar files are there. I am completely baffled as to how it could look in the directory that contains the pom and not find it. Has anyone had any experiences with this?

Comment: stupid question, your locally published project IS scala 2.9.1 and not scala 2.9.2 right ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a .dependsOn call too, I think.

```
val timeywimeyentities: Project = Project([Put all of your settings here for the project just like you would a play project])

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(   
    resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://" + Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/.m2/repository",testOptions in Test := Nil 
).dependsOn(timeywimeyentities % "compile->compile")
```

Adding "compile->compile" makes the main code of your play project rely on the main code of your dependency. If you wanted to make the test code of your play project also depend on it, you could use "compile->test". If you want only the test code of both to see each other, you could use "test->test". You can also chain them together, for example: "compile->compile;test->test". If all you want is "compile->compile", you need not explicitly state it.

See https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Multi-Project for more information.